# How to populate a UIPickerView with results from a NSFetchRequest using Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, xcode6, uipickerview

I have a UIPickerView that I am trying populate with the results from a NSFetchRequest pulling data from a managedObjectContext.  When I initialize my UIPickerView with the following, `KCModalPickerView *pickerView = [[KCModalPickerView alloc] initWithValues:_userNames];` Xcode doesn't throw and warnings or errors, but when I build and run the app I am getting the following error.

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Account copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7a60ec70'
*** First throw call stack:

Now before you say this error is due to me not implementing the `copyWithZone` method in my vc, I want to point out that nowhere in my class files am I using the keyword `copy`

The method that I was told that is causinging the crash belongs to the `KCModalPicker` class implementation file.  And the method looks like the following,

```
// edit this method
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
 return [self.values objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

What do I need to change / edit / add to prevent this app from crashing?

***Update***

_usernames is a NSArray ...the results look like the following,

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Account" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[[entity propertiesByName] objectForKey:@"username"]];
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray _usernames = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

Comment: What does `_usernames` point to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`KCModalPickerView` expects an array of `NSString`, you give it an array of `Account`. The framework tries to copy your instance because it thinks it's an `NSString`, which conforms to the `NSCopying` protocol and implements `copyWithZone:`. Your object does not, and there will be a `[Account copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance` exception.

Simply create an array of NSStrings by using the appropriate attribute from your Core Data object.

There are probably smarter ways for this, but this would be the obvious solution:

```
NSMutableArray *names = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[_usernames count]];
for (Account *account in _usernames) {
    NSString *accountName = account.name;
    if (!accountName) {
        accountName = @"<Unknown Account>";
    }
    [names addObject:accountName];
}
KCModalPickerView *pickerView = [[KCModalPickerView alloc] initWithValues:names];
```

---

I just saw that you have set `propertiesToFetch`. Additionally you have to set `resultsType` of the fetchRequest to `NSDictionaryResultType`. In this case `executeFetchRequest:error:` returns an array of dictionaries. And you should be able to use `NSArray *names = [_usernames valueForKey:@"username"];` instead of the for loop.

Comment: thank you so much for a thorough answer.  This is something I have been struggling with for a couple of days now. :-?